# Excel - matching records between worksheets based on more than one column

Tags: excel

I have two worksheets
basic format of them both is:

- C1,lastname,firstname,c4,c5,c6

I am trying to make a column on the second worksheet (which is significantly smaller then the other one) that tells me if a record worksheet 2 matches a record in worksheet 1, based on the first and last name.

This filter almost got me what I wanted:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2:C2,Table2[last name]:Table2[First Name],0)),"user gone","user exists")
```

Except it would return true if user's first name matched another's first name in worksheet 1 and user's last name matched someone else's last name. Example:

- worksheet two has jane doe, looking for jane doe in worksheet one
- worksheet one has jane jill and john doe, but no jane doe. code comes up true
- if worksheet one only had one of those users, then i get false

I need the filter to return true only if jane doe exists in both lists.
How can i tweak my filter to do this? i keep finding ways to match single columns in records not multi columns between records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with an array formula.

Be sure to enter as an array formula using *ctrl+shift+enter*:

```
=IF(SUM((B2=Table2[last name])*(C2=Table2[First Name])*1),"user exists","user gone")
```

The sum searches for the name and returns a one or a zero, and the if statement assigns it a value.

Comment: Sorry I missed your comment, but the equalities return arrays of zeros and ones, with ones in the rows where the equality holds.  The arrays of zeros and ones multiplied together gives an array with with ones in the rows where both equalities hold (and zeros elsewhere), and then the sum adds them all up.  The if statement uses the result with zero being false and anything greater than zero being true.  I hope this helps!

Comment: so basically we are using functions in a sort of way that they were not really meant for but though clever manipulation it works.
is there a way to pull a piece of data from the record it help true? there doesn't seem to be a way and it's really not important, but i'm curious.

Comment: Array formulas are pretty powerful; I'm not sure it's entirely an unintended use.  As for pulling other data, you could maybe use the formula to return an index and then do a vlookup.  By the way, if this answer solved your question, would you mind accepting it?